# De onde vem a expressão "achados e perdidos"?

Tags: significado, ortografia, português-brasileiro, origem-histórica

Em instituições públicas como: escolas, restaurantes, clubes, etc existe um local destinado para se guardar objetos perdidos. As pessoas que perdem algum objeto nesses locais, logo pensam: tomara que esteja nos "achados e perdidos".

É interessante que até a agência de correspondências do Brasil (Correios) criou um serviço de "achados e perdidos" de documentos.

> [Achados e perdidos](http://www2.correios.com.br/servicos/achados_perdidos/default.cfm)
>   Perdeu seus documentos?
>   Verifique primeiramente se seu nome consta na relação de achados e perdidos dos Correios...

O restaurante da Universidade de Brasília possui um [site](http://www.ru.unb.br/achados-e-perdidos) e normas para controle dos objetos perdidos.

De onde vem a expressão "achados e perdidos"? Não deveria ser "perdidos e achados"?

Comment: Em Portugal é _perdidos e achados_. Por exemplo, no site do Público (jornal), a proporção via Google é 53/2.

Comment: Sim nunca tinha ouvido "Achados e Perdidos", em Portugal pelo menos ouço sempre "Perdidos e Achados". E pela ordem natural das coisas acho que faz todo o sentido, algo tem de ser perdido antes de poder ser achado.

Comment: Não há ordem para perdas e achados pois são perdas e achados distintos. Mas em pt-BR usamos 'achados e perdidos", pois pessoas acham coisas e entregam no lugar, e pessoas perdem coisas e procuram por lá.

Comment: Essa expressão também existe no inglês, "lost and found". De acordo com o artigo em inglês na Wikipedia, existem relatos da utilização dessa expressão desde a Grécia Antiga, que abrange um período desde 1100 a.C. Aparentemente a expressão se espalhou poraí com o tempo.

Comment: Onde moro é mais popular a expressão "Perdidos e achados"

Answer (score 1):

Não há uma regra quanto a ordem "Achados e Perdidos" ou "Perdidos e Achados".
"Achados" quer dizer que alguém achou o que outra pessoa perdeu, e assim, levou para o posto de itens perdidos. Assim como "Perdidos" se refere de uma forma mais específica aos itens que foram perdidos.